# Node.js http.get xml is returned 'escaped'

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, aws-lambda

I am working on a simple AWS Lambda function in Javascript (Node 6.x) which should 'proxy' an RSS of an italian news provider.

This is the code of the function:

```
var http = require("http")

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    http.get("http://www.milanotoday.it/rss/", (response) => {
        response.setEncoding("utf8")

        let xml = ""
        response.on("data", (chunk) => { xml += chunk })
        response.on("end", () => { callback(null, xml) })
    })
}
```

It works, or at least it loads the response inside the `xml` variable.
I can't get why the string is something like this:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n<rss version=\"2.0\" xmlns:content=\"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/\"...
```

It seems to be sort of 'escaped'.

Can somebody help me?
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.get` is probably working just fine. If you run your code outside of the AWS ecosystem, you'll see that you are getting unescaped XML from `http.get`. The problem is that Lambda wants you to return JSON so when you pass the string to the callback it gets escaped.

If you are running this function through API Gateway you can do a transform in the integration response. The way to do this is to return an object from your lambda:

```
callback(null, {myXML: xml}))
```

Then in the API Gateway go to the integration response area under your `GET` (or POST) resource and click the arrow next to the `200` response. This should reveal an area for body mappings. You want to add a mapping for `application/xml` and then add something like:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
$inputRoot.myXML
```

This should get you nice clean XML. It's a little hard to describe so I'll post a screen shot that might help:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes have to be escaped inside a double quoted string (Makes sense, right?). Now you just have to parse the XML, using for instance [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js)

Comment: It makes sense, the fact is that I shouldn't get the external double quotes at all. I think I probably don't need xml2js either because the only purpouse of the function is to return the xml to the client, which than use it with jquery native methods.